# 'update available' pop up not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My app checks if there is update available in app store. I call this in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method.

```
(BOOL)checkIfNeedsUpdate {
    BOOL needsUpdate = NO;
    NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];

    NSString* appID = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/ph/lookup?bundleId=%@", appID]];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary* lookup = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    if([lookup[@"resultCount"] integerValue] == 1) {
        NSString* appStoreVersion = lookup[@"results"][0][@"version"];
        NSString* currentVersion = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
        if(![appStoreVersion isEqualToString:currentVersion]) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"logined"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            needsUpdate = YES;
        }
    }

    return needsUpdate;
}
```

So to test this, I downgraded the app version that I have and run it on the simulator and this works like a charm. However, when I try running the app on my device the "Update Available" pop up is not displaying thus not updating the app. Any idea what is wrong with my code? How can I display the "Update Available" pop up to be able to update.

Any help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Here's the the uialertview:

[image: versions]

Comment: Did you check the version of the app "when I try running the app on my device"?

Comment: make UIAlertView and on alert show both current and updated version so  that we can confirm that your code is working fine

Comment: @RahulMishra i have posted an image with the uialertview

Comment: @anhtu yes..i checked the current version and the one from app store..

Comment: Can you print value of ` NSString* appStoreVersion = lookup[@"results"][0][@"version"];
        NSString* currentVersion = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];` when running on the device?

Comment: Make sure your device connect to the Internet also.

Comment: @anhtu App Store Version:1.0 Current Version:0.9 just like the data printed on the uialertview. I added an image of the alertview.

Comment: So, for sure `needsUpdate = YES;`. Right? That means the problem not here. Can you show more code? where do you show alert....

Comment: Start with overriding the lookup altogether by returning YES. In case alert does not show you might want to post the code responsible for showing the alert. It could be that you are showing it too soon or from the wrong view controller.

Comment: @rokjarc isnt the "Update Available" pop up should automatically show once it detects there is an available update? The alertview image that I posted was to check the versions.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. Yeah, you can take care of showing the popup on your own or you can delegate some 3rd party library to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve my problem. Thanks to @rokjarc's comment.
Here's how I did it:

```
(void)checkIfNeedsUpdate {
    NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    NSString* appID = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/ph/lookup?bundleId=%@", appID]];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary* lookup = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    if([lookup[@"resultCount"] integerValue] == 1) {
        NSString* appStoreVersion = lookup[@"results"][0][@"version"];
        NSString* currentVersion = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
        if(![appStoreVersion isEqualToString:currentVersion]) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"logined"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            [[Harpy sharedInstance] checkVersion];
        }
    }
}
```

I used [Harpy](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy) - third party library to inform user's that there is an update for the app in app store.
Thanks to the people who took a minute to read my inquiry.